# Using jQuery fadeToggle for navigation bar, how to show/hide content one at a time?

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle

I am *very* new to CSS/Jquery so please forgive the assumed simplicity of this question.

I have a navigation links to: ABOUT and CONTACT. I have figured out how to fadeToggle their content. However, if you click one link followed by a different one, their content fades in/out sequentially and stack on top of each other. I would like for the content of each link to automatically fade out if a different link is clicked on. For example, if the user clicks "CONTACT", the contact information will fade in. Then, if the user clicks "ABOUT" I would like for the contact information to fade out and the about information to fade in. Can anyone help in lay language?

What I have so far in **HTML**/CSS/JS:

```
<body>

<div id="navbar">    
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>    
</div>

<div id="aboutcontent" class="hidden">
 <p> ABOUT ME </p>
</div>

<div id="contactcontent" class="hidden">
<p>NAME, CITY, EMAIL, PHONE NUMBER</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {display:none}          
#navbar ul li { display: inline;}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#contact').click(function() {
$('div#contactcontent').fadeToggle();
return false;
});

$('a#about').click(function() {
$('div#aboutcontent').fadeToggle();
return false;  


});   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a#contact').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#aboutcontent').hide();      
    $('div#contactcontent').fadeIn(); 
  });


  $('a#about').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#contactcontent').hide();  
    $('div#aboutcontent').fadeIn();  
  });   

});
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ECBhr/1/

Answer (score 0):

**like this you mean** Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hgVLH/3/

Hope this helps,

API: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

or you can use `.hide()` = http://api.jquery.com/hide/ http://jsfiddle.net/hgVLH/4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/hgVLH/5/

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#contact').click(function() {
        $('div#aboutcontent').fadeOut();
        $('div#contactcontent').fadeToggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('a#about').click(function() {
        $('div#contactcontent').fadeOut();
        $('div#aboutcontent').fadeToggle();
        return false;


    });
});
```